.Net6 : Condition for Farsi date in database tables?
I have a table that has a field in which the solar date is recorded as a string.
I want to get only the data whose date is equal to the input date
CultureInfo persianCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
DateTime searchDateInput = DateTime.Parse("1402/02/05", persianCulture);
_context.table.Where(g => DateTime.Parse(g.DateAdd, persianCulture) == searchDateInput);

I searched a lot but did not find a suitable solution!!!

If the value in the database is stored as a string, then isn't this just a string equality test? Note: it my be worth considering whether it is an option to store the value using the database's date/datetime primitives, and worrying about the presentation in the UI layer, but I appreciate that may not always be possible, especially in an observation-based calendar

Don't do that conversion in the where; either search the table by string, or change the table to store a date and search by date. Always, always strive to avoid performing data conversions in a WHERE clause - it makes your queries slow, and prevents use of any indexes you have on the column

@flackoverstow I can't save the date in solar format with datetime format

Mmm, it sounds more like a misunderstanding of how databases store data. A DateTime represents a single moment in the time stream of the universe, and it typically (internally to a particular db) does so numerically, for example "x milliseconds after time Y". I'm this certain that your database is capable of storing the date and time of the event you're interested in, with great accuracy. Formatting is done when you put a date up on screen. We don't typically store them as strings because we have to convert them when we want to do anything at all with them, even workout if X is before Y etc
